# ajax post to fit webApi signature

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

How to write jquery ajax post (or put) to match the following .Net webApi signature:

```
    public bool PostValue(Guid id, string Field, string Value)
    {            
        return true;
    }


 $.ajax({
            url: "/api/item/PostValue/" + id,
            contentType: "text/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'Field': 'bar',
                'Value': 'nolibri'
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Ajax request is a post statement you have to add a [HttpPost] header to your method

```
[HttpPost]
public bool PostValue(Guid id, string Field, string Value)
{            
   return true;
}
```

EDIT:
Also you have to edit your data in your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/api/item/PostValue/",
contentType: "text/json",
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
data: {
   'id' : id
   'Field': 'bar',
   'Value': 'nolibri'
},
success: function (result) {
   //
   }
});
```